# Чем эпический театр отличается от обычного(по Станиславскому)?

Tags: литература, литературоведение

Не могу понять почему так много систем?

Comment: А почему вопрос задан именно на этом сайте?

Comment: @shampar, А на каком можно ещё?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не соответствует тематике сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Само название и говорит о разнице: театр Станиславского - психологический театр переживаний, где актёр вживается в роль, а мы ему сопереживаем, а эпический театр - повествует, рассказывает историю персонажа -  и сам автор рассказывает, общаясь со зрителем, и хор песню споёт, где выскажет отношение к персонажу, и танец возможен, и диафильм на задней стене, и просто надпись на белом полотне  или прямо на  стене, и какой-то персонаж поспорит с автором - и всё на глазах у зрителя, чтобы тот понял "сверхзадачу" - идею.

Что такое эпос? Э́пос — род литературы, героическое повествование о прошлом, содержащее **целостную картину народной жизни** и представляющее в гармоническом единстве мир героев. Часто эпические поэмы не имеют автора. Повествование ведётся от лица повествователя — реального или вымышленного рассказчика, наблюдателя, участника или героя события.
 Вот и в эпическом театре больше не игры, а повествования, хотя и игра важна, но она уже по Станиславскому - с вживанием в роль.

Comment: спасибо.!!!!!!!!